# Sublime text beautify PHP serialized data

Tags: php, serialization, sublimetext3

I deal with serialized PHP data a lot (wp developer) and I'd like to know if anyone out there has figured out how to beautify serialized php data from within ST3. I'd like to be able to view my serialized php data in a nice indented format in the same way that I can already view my JSON and other serialized data formats. There are plenty of tools online that do this, but i'd like on integrated into ST3.

There is a PHP beautifier out there which i believe runs the PHP_Beautifier PEAR package, but it does nothing to serialized data (probably because the extra whitespace would break the format).
I have had relative luck with copying the data to a new file and running a regex replace `/(.*?);(.*?);/$1 : $2,/` and then running `Format as Javascript` from `CodeFormatter`. but obviously this quite a bit of work to do each time.

I'm new to ST3 so I'd like some opinions on what my best option is here. Is there a solution out there or should I create a plugin to send the string to an online beautifier, or write a macro or something?

Cheers

Comment: Looks like I will be contributing PHP functionality to the SerializedDataConverter repo in order to make this happen unless I get a better answer. https://github.com/facelessuser/SerializedDataConverter/issues/10#issuecomment-151509444

Comment: Check out: https://github.com/marcobalk/UniQTools and follow the instructions. There's a couple packages in the repo there just for this!

Answer (score -2):

I am afraid that PHP serialized data cannot be formatted (like JSON or XML)

Serialized PHP strings can contain really complex and deeply nested details, non-ASCII strings will be base64 encoded, and referenced objects are embedded in the serialized string. Making such potentially complex serialized strings look neat can be tough.

I guess, that the high complexity of the process, and the very limited usability of such a beautified string, there is no ST3 package for this.

The closest thing you can do is to deserialize the data for display and then re-serialize it before saving the file.
A simple (non-ST3) tool for this is https://www.unserialize.com/

#### Why do you want to pretty-print a serialized string? (Off Topic)

I guess you want to debug something, and think that pretty-printing the serialized string is the fastest/easiest solution.

Simply `unserialize()`ing + `var_dump()`ing the result is a straightforward process that gives you the best overview of the data.

I know, this is not the OP's question, but since you're reading this page, you might want to ask yourself if you really want to *pretty-print serialized data* or if you just need to *debug the object*. If it's the latter, then go with https://www.unserialize.com or similar tools

Comment: I didn't get that he was asking to store the data back as indented serialized data. Just that he wanted to beautify it.